# Don't understand scipy.optimize.brute syntax

Tags: python, scipy

I don't understand the syntax of `scipy.optimize.brute` at all. If I have a list, say `[-1, 0, 1]`, and a univariate function `x**2`, how do I get it to minimize over that list? I've read [the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.brute.html), and I don't know what to pass it. Tuples don't work, neither do lists, and I don't know what a 'slice object' is or why it is being passed two slice objects for that matter.

MWE:

```
import scipy.optimize as spopt

def f(x):
    return x**2

print(spopt.brute(f, ([-1, 0, 1])))
```

gives me `TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`scipy.optimize.brute`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.brute.html) **minimizes** a function over a given range.
The error relies in the way you pass the `ranges` arguments. As stated in the documentation:

> Each component of the ranges tuple must be either a “slice object” or a range tuple of the form (low, high).

Here an example.

```
>>> res = spopt.brute(func=f, ranges=(slice(-1,2,1),), full_output=True)
>>> res
(array([ 0.]), 0.0, array([-1,  0,  1]), array([1, 0, 1]))
>>> res[0]
array([ 0.]) # global minimum
>>> res[1]
0.0 # function value at global minimum
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for me. What I get:
`File "C:\Code\Conda\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 2893, in brute
    N = len(ranges)`
`TypeError: object of type 'slice' has no len()`